# Bulk Upsert exception in ElasticSearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using bulk update and have set `doc_as_upsert": true`. But I am getting error : document_missing_exception.

```
"update": {
"_index": "index_name",
"_type": "doc_type",
"_id": "1234",
"status": 404,
"error": {
"type": "document_missing_exception",
"reason": "[doc_type][1234]: document missing",
"index_uuid": "q7Yl-ftoS4WD3eE1j0D0kQ",
"shard": "3",
"index": "index_name"
}
}
```

Any idea what I am missing. I am using Spring Boot for the same. ES version is 6.4

Comment: Hi, Could you please add your bulk query, as well? Thanks!

Comment: Map<String, Map<String, Object>> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
nestedMap.put("doc", Map<String,Object>map);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.putAll(nestedMap);

String query = JSON.toJSONString(json);


Update.Builder builder = new Update.Builder(query)
            .index(index_name)
            .type(index_type).id(documentId)
            .setParameter("doc_as_upsert", true);

jestClient.execute(new Bulk.Builder().addAction(builder.build()).build());


@saeednasehi